# Docker backend service is suddenly stopping while docker service stays running, why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-engine

I am running docker on a windows server 2019 VM. Docker has been working fine on that machine for a year now. But suddenly, last week docker engine was suddenly stopping and so all the containers were not running. Note that the server was not restarted since December (2 months ago).
When I log into the machine as administrator and click on the whale icon, everything restarts but I want to know what the issue is and how I can resolve it without having to log into the server on a daily basis and restart the service.

I set up windows monitoring for com.docker.backend and com.docker.service with elapsed time counter which shows how long the services have been up for.
The graphs clearly show that at one point docker backend dies and only restarts when I log in as Administrator to the server.

I also restart docker engine in debug mode hoping that that will give us more information but unfortunately all it shows is the logs when the docker engine is running and not a single piece of info on why it stopped.